# WPF Treeview Expand Action

Tags: wpf, click, treeview

im trying to add a button inside every item of the treeview.When the button is clicked:
- expand the tree if there are some item of the selected parent 
- if not a parent: do an action. 
The double action will allow me to remove completely the togglebutton.
So this is what i figured out so far:

```
        <TreeView>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
                    <Button  Content ="{Binding Title}" Click="OnItemClick"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

My next step is to change the style of the treeview in order to have only a button that does all the work. So depending if its a parent of something or not, the button will expand for new item or will do an action inside the code.

```
    public void OnItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        FrameworkElement parent = (FrameworkElement)((Button)sender).Parent;

        if (parent is TreeViewItem)
        {
            //ACTION

        }
        else
           //EXPAND
        Console.WriteLine(parent);

    }
```

So when I get the parent element of the button I want to check if the parent button (treeitemview) is expandible or not. But for now the parent I get is always null.
So the blocking step is:

- is there a way do get the type of the parent of the button (treeitemview) and check if it is expandible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following helper method to find the parent `TreeViewItem` in the visual tree:

```
private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
    if (parent == null)
        return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

Usage:

```
TreeViewItem parent = FindParent<TreeViewItem>((Button)sender);
if (parent != null)
    //ACTION
```

Comment: A really nice solution, really clean. PS: if someone asks.... the parent object will return you the number of items inside the "possible" parent. In this way you will expand the parent treeview or not. Thank you